# Rep when question transferred

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to rep when a question is moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/what-happens-to-rep-when-a-question-is-moved)

What will happen to my rep if my answer is selected on a question which is later transferred to another stackexchange site?  Will I lose it?  Will it be transferred on my account of the recipient site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a post is moved from site A to site B. You lose the effect of the votes on site A and you gain the effect of the votes on site B. So the new rep is found.

It is also possible to lose rep (if you hit the rep cap on site B) and you can create rep (if you had hit the rep cap on site A).

If you have no account on site B, the rep is magically stored. So you get it when you create an account on site B.